# Get a plot like spectrogram in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, fft, spectrogram, contourf

I would like to get a plot of the same type of the one that I get with `spectrogram` function, I am trying with `contour` but I do not get the same result. I have written a small function which compares the two plot. The function records audio for one second and then plot the spectrogram.

```
function graph_comparison
    a = audiorecorder(44100,16,1);
    recordblocking(a,1);
    y = getaudiodata(a);
    figure
    subplot(1,2,1);
    spectrogram(y);
    s = spectrogram(y);
    subplot(1,2,2);
    contour(mag2db(abs(s))); %mag2db converts intensity in db
    %rotate the second plot
    view(-90, 90); 
    set(gca, 'ydir', 'reverse');
end
```

Example of plot result:
[image]

Comment: If you want to achieve the same result of `spectrogram`, why you don't simply use it?

Comment: because I need to manipulate data first, so in my real code I use the variable `s`, but I like the kind of plot given by `spectrogram`.

Answer (score 1):

I found it, it is sufficient to replace `contour` with `imagesc`.

Comment: You can also try `contourf`.

Comment: Thanks, but looks uglier than contour if with a lot of levels And otherwise I get few informations

Comment: Yup, `imagesc` is the way to go. But be careful with imagesc: when you call `imagesc(x, y, z)`, it doesn’t assign pixel locations to `x` and `y`. E.g., this works: `imagesc([-1 1], [10 20], randn(100,100))`, because `imagesc` just uses `x` and `y` to get the extents. That's one confusion that took a while it figure out.

Comment: @AhmedFasih actually setting 'LineColor' to 'none', with contourf I can use a lot of levels and get still a good plot! Thank you